# Django 1.6 Admin Page Overriding Not Working

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

We're trying to override the admin page for Django 1.6, but it continues to get it from django/contrib/templates/...:

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [
                [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            ],
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                    # list if you haven't customized them:
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                    'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
                'loaders': [
                    # insert your TEMPLATE_LOADERS here
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                ]
            },
        },
    ]
]
```

and the files structure:

```
project
  project 
    templates
      app_name
      admin 
        file_to_override <--it varies here from being inside the app_name or inside template itself
```

I'm not sure why the directories arent working

Comment: Try to put your custom registration templates inside `registration` folder. It should be inside your current `templates` folder. (You can try to rename your `admin` folder to `registration` inside your templates).

Comment: the admin page works by using loader.py which is asking for admin/index.html; I'm getting a TemplateDoesNotExist for that path because I'm trying to move away from the given templates; to test that I took out the django/contrib/templates out of that folder to see if it would pickup ones that I've placed there.

Comment: Try to put your `app_directories` inside your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` above the filesystem loader to load it first

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using Django 1.6, but the TEMPLATES dict syntax you quote is only for Django 1.8+. In previous versions, you need to specify all the options individually.

Also note you have wrongly surrounded the DIRS value with *two* list brackets.

```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
   ]
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ]
        TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_LOADERS here
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ]
```

Comment: Ah I wasn't sure if it was purely a 1.8 thing. This is an older project that we're working on that is using 1.6--However it was i nthe format you suggested earlier and that didn't work nor did it work when I changed it back,

Comment: Please check the double list thing I mentioned.

Comment: Yea, I fixed that also